# Спорный синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

**Труппа отразилась вверх ногами, в смешном(,) изогнутом и растянутом виде.**

*Смешном*, *изогнутом*, *растянутом* — определения. А какой это член предложения — ***в виде***? Тоже определение или обстоятельство? Ведь навряд ли можно сказать: отразилась (как?) в виде!

Answer (score 4):

Труппа **(подлежащее)** отразилась **(сказуемое)** вверх ногами **(обстоятельство образа действия)**, (однородные определения: близки в контексте) в смешном **(определение)**, изогнутом **(определение)** и растянутом **(определение)** виде **(обстоятельство)**.

Отразилась (как?) в виде; в виде (каком?) смешном, изогнутом и расстянутом.

Comment: Но ведь "в виде"здесь не вполне самостоятельное сочетание.

Comment: @Серж и что? Мы же делаем грамматический разбор; грамматически оно независимо. Нет?

Comment: Грамматически оно требует после себя дополнение.